# Twelve friends and their birthdays

Tags: combinatorics

Twelve friends: Anna, Bill, Deb, Dory, Eliza, Gaby, Jan, John, Judy, Mary, Otto and Sam, were talking about their birthdays, and much to their surprise discovered that they were all born on different months and, in fact, that each of them was born on a month with at least two different letters in common with their own name.

**In what months were each of the twelve friends born?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess:

> ```
>  Anna   January 
>  Bill   April 
>  Deb    September 
>  Dory   December 
>  Eliza  February 
>  Gaby   May 
>  Jan    June 
>  John   November 
>  Judy   July 
>  Mary   March 
>  Otto   October 
>  Sam    August
> ```

How?

> Anna can only be January, Bill only April. Deb any of September, October, November and December. Otto can only be October, Jan only June, Eliza only February. July can only be Judy. Then John is November, Dory December and Deb is September.
>
> ```
>  Anna   January 
>  Bill   April 
>  Deb    September
>  Dory   December
>  Eliza  February
>  Gaby   May August
>  Jan    June
>  John   November
>  Judy   July 
>  Mary   March May
>  Otto   October 
>  Sam    March May August
> ```
>
> This gives us three answers, one if Gaby is May and two if she is August.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

> ```
> Anna    January
> Bill    April
> Deb     September
> Dory    December
> Eliza   February
> Gaby    August
> Jan     June
> John    November
> Judy    July
> Mary    May
> Otto    October
> Sam     March
> ```